# I am trying to upload a file and save the file path to my database so as to be able to access it

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save file paths to a database and move the files to a given directory. The file path gets save to the database but the files don't get uploaded. Please help

I tried to specify the file path and rename the file

Here is my controller:

```
public function uploadId(Request $request)
    {
        $pathOne = $request->file('front_id')->move('public/verify/', 'front_id'.time());
        $pathTwo = $request->file('back_id')->move('images/verify/', 'back_id'.time());
        $pathThree = $request->file('address')->move('images/verify/', 'address'.time());

        $identification = new Identification;
        $identification->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $identification->front_id = $pathOne;
        $identification->back_id = $pathTwo;
        $identification->address = $pathThree;

        $identification->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with("success", "Your ID's has successfully been uploaded.");
    }
```

I expect that the file gets saved to the database and uploaded to the directory but that's not the case. The file path only gets saved.

Comment: Just use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary and relax about what do you want to do with the files :)

Comment: This doesn't help much because I still do not know how to implement it and I need some simpler as I am quite new to laravel

Comment: It's not good practice to store files in the database as it'll only increase database size in the feature. Store image in storage and store path in the database is the optimal way.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but the files don't get stored and the file path on the database don't show the correct file name

Comment: @KingKesh The spatie laravel-medialibrary package above is very helpful as well, please consider utilizing it

Answer (score 0):

You aren't storing the files anywhere in your code. You can't move a file that hasn't been saved yet.

`$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');`